# glob pattern to match two dates simultaneously

Tags: php, date, glob

I'm using glob in this format at the moment:

```
glob('/STORAGE/LOGFILES/*.*')
```

Within /STORAGE/LOGFILES, there are hundreds of text files that all begin with YYYY-MM-DD.  I'd like to change the `*.*` in my pattern to instead only look at the current month and previous month:

```
glob('/STORAGE/LOGFILES/2013-04*')
glob('/STORAGE/LOGFILES/2013-03*')
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to do this in a single statement.  I think I've figured out how to do the current month:

```
glob('/STORAGE/LOGFILES/'.date("Y-m").'*')
```

but I'd like a way to combine it all into a single statement.  Appreciate any help and thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GLOB_BRACE` option like this:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$lastMonth = new DateTime('-1 month');
$monthList = $now->format('Y-m').','.$lastMonth->format('Y-m');
$pattern = '/STORAGE/LOGFILES/{'.$monthList.'}*';
glob($pattern, GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: The solution with `DateTime` is much smoother than mine. I always forget about that fancy new stuff. :D

Comment: Thank you - worked perfectly!  Thanks to everyone else for posting your answers - really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
glob('/STORAGE/LOGFILES/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]*')
```

You can play with glob pattern : http://cowburn.info/2010/04/30/glob-patterns/
Have fun

Comment: That's not what he asked for

Comment: How does this relate to the question? This pattern matches everything in the directory, not only the current and the previous month.

Comment: Regardless of this it is twice useful then other posts! +1

Comment: @hek2mgl useful for what purpose? It's just a very bad regexp, even if the user were looking for that kind of solution the pattern should be rewritten in a better way.

Comment: Useful for one who came from google to this, using: 'glob date php'. And find a really customized question. But, he will find the great answer of @GoT .. Thanks again! :) However, Uby, yours is well too.. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that is platform (or shell) depended.

> The glob() function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern
>   according to the rules used by the libc glob() function, which is
>   similar to the rules used by common shells.

See this note: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#110340

```
<?php

$a = glob('/path/*{foo,bar}.dat',GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($a);

?>

Result : 
Array
(
    [0] => /path/file_foo.dat
    [1] => /path/file_foobar.dat
    [2] => /path/file_foobar.dat
)
```

Maybe you could try an '|' or sign as well?

Doesn't it support regex: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#88250 ?

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
glob('/STORAGE/LOGFILES/'.date("Y").'-{'.date("m").','.date("m")-1.'}*',GLOB_BRACE)
```